# Result from custom View launching Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I've got a custom `View` that, when touched, launches an `Activity`.  I'd like this custom `View` to follow proper object oriented methodologies, so I want it independent of any particular `Activity` that might be displaying the `View`.

To recap:  `Activity` 1 contains custom `View`.  Custom `View` launches `Activity` 2.

So far, so good.  I can call `getContext()` from within my `View` to launch `Activity` 2.  It looks like this:

```
Context con = getContext();
Intent launcher = new Intent(con, TimeWizard.class);
((Activity) con).startActivityForResult(launcher, LAUNCH_TIME);
```

As hinted at in the third line, I want to get the return of that `Activity`, but it ends up in `Activity` 1's `onActivityResult()`.  That means that `Activity` 1 now needs to know about the inner workings of that custom `View`, which is less than ideal - even unacceptable under some circumstances.

So what I'd like to do is have that `View` launch `Activity` 2 and then get the result directly.  Is there a way to do this?  I feel like I must be missing the obvious answer here.  My workaround has been to use `Activity` 1's `onActivityResult()` to pass the result back to the `View`.  It's functional, but very messy.

Comment: Did you figure out any solution for this?

Comment: I wish I could say I found the elegant solution I was looking for, but I ended up using the messy method I listed above.

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing something similar. I tried to make it less messy by creating this kind of interface: 

    `public interface ActivityResultForwarder {
      public static interface ActivityResultListener {
        void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
      }
      
      void startActivityForForwarding(Intent intent, int requestCode, ActivityResultListener listener);
    }`

Thanks for the reply anyway!